# Python Get User Fullname From Foreign Key Customer

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i want to get the customer fullname, but in the end i only get the id.

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(restaurant=request.user.restaurant).order_by('customer__id').values('customer__id', 'customer__address', 'customer__avatar', 'customer').annotate(total_order= Count('customer__id'))
```

in value('customer') i want get the customer fullname but i only get the id.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name= 'customer')
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length= 500, blank= True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length= 500, blank= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the content of orders?

Comment: <thead>
     <tr class="bg-gray text-white">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Customer Avatar</th>
      <th>Customer Address</th>
      <th>Total Order</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     {% for order in orders %}
      <tr>
       <td scope="row">{{order.customer__id}}</td>
       <td>{{order.customer}}</td>
       <td>{{order.customer__avatar}}</td>
       <td>{{order.customer__address}}</td>
       <td>{{order.total_order}}</td>
      </tr>
     {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

Comment: the order model

Comment: class Order(models.Model):
 customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
 restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
 driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, blank= True, null= True)
 address = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
 total = models.IntegerField()
 status = models.IntegerField(choices= STATUS_CHOICES)
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(default= timezone.now)
 picked_at = models.DateTimeField(blank= True, null= True)

 def __str__(self):
  return str(self.id)

Comment: @VikoWijaya You can edit your original question to include additional information instead of posting comments or answers.

Answer (score 1):

That's how `values` and `values_list` methods work. For foreign keys, they return the id (or whatever unique field to foreign key points at). I'm worried you either need to fetch the user object separately, or instead of `.values` use `.select_related` (or `.prefetch_related`).

By the way, the `.annotate` causes a `GROUP BY` on all the non-annotated fields passed to `.values`, in this case `customer__address` and `customer__avatar`.

Comment: using my code i can already show what i want, but not the fullname.

Comment: Customer Name    Address   total order
abc                         abcabc     2
bbb                          bbbb        1
ccc                          cccc          1

something like that

Comment: As I said, `.values` and `.values_list` do not return instances of models. Only raw values (primary keys in case of foreign key fields). If you want to make it cleanly, you can create a `get_user_full_name` function which takes a user or a user id and returns user's fullname, and reuse that function in your view and `Customer.__str__` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I use:

```
orders = Order.objects.select_related('customer').filter(restaurant= request.user.restaurant).annotate(total_order= Count('customer'))
```

[image]

it becomes like that, I want the pablo 1 row but the total order is 2.